# Emulating Matlab Mesh Plot in Matplotlib yielding shadow effects

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure, figure

I have this meshplot that looks very clean in matlab for a 3d surface (Ignore the red border line):
[image]

And I am trying to emulate the same image in matplotlib. However, I get this weird shadow effect where the top of the surface is pure black and only the bottom is white:
[image]

I have the code for both plots here *my surface u can be replaced with any 3d data(ie peaks)

matlab

```
dx=0.01;
dt=0.001; %Attention : they have to be integer-multiples of one another
T=1.999; %length of simulation

x=(0:dx:1);
t=(0:dt:T);
u = load('u.mat', 'u');
u = u.u;
u2 = load('u2.mat','u');
u2 = u2.u;
pstep = 3;
tstep = 30;
xzeros = repelem(1, 1, length(t));
zline = interp2(x, t, u, xzeros, t);
zline2 = interp2(x, t, u2, xzeros, t);
subplot(1, 2, 1);
mesh(x(1:pstep:end),t(1:tstep:end),u(1:tstep:end,1:pstep:end), "edgecolor", "black");
    view(90, 10);
    xlabel('x', 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    ylabel('Time', 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    zlabel('u(x,t)', 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    set(gca,'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    hold on
    plot3(xzeros, t, zline, 'r', 'linewidth', 3);
subplot(1, 2, 2)   
mesh(x(1:pstep:end),t(1:tstep:end),u2(1:tstep:end,1:pstep:end), "edgecolor", "black");
    view(90, 10);
    xlabel('x', 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    ylabel('Time', 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    zlabel('u(x,t)', 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    set(gca,'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize',18)
    hold on
   plot3(xzeros, t, zline2, 'r', 'linewidth', 3);
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
sgtitle("$$\hat{u}$ for PDE Solutions Using $\hat{k}$$", 'interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 32)
saveas(gca, "matlab.png");
```

and matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.03, bottom=0, right=0.98, top=1, wspace=0.1, hspace=0)
subfigs = fig.subfigures(nrows=1, ncols=1, hspace=0)

subfig = subfigs
subfig.suptitle(r"$\hat{u}$ for PDE Solutions Using $\hat{k}$")
ax = subfig.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax[0].plot_surface(x, t, uarr[0], edgecolor="black",lw=0.2, rstride=30,
                       cstride=3,
                        alpha=1, color="white")
ax[0].view_init(5, 5)
ax[0].set_xlabel("x", labelpad=10)
ax[0].set_ylabel("Time")
ax[0].set_zlabel(r"$\hat{u}(x, t)$", labelpad=5)
ax[0].zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
ax[1].plot_surface(x, t, uarr[2], edgecolor="black",lw=0.2, rstride=30,
                       cstride=3,
                        alpha=1,color="white")
ax[1].view_init(5, 5)
ax[1].set_xlabel("x", labelpad=10)
ax[1].set_ylabel("Time")
ax[1].set_zlabel(r"$\hat{u}(x, t)$", labelpad=5)
ax[1].zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
```

Any ideas on relieving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for `plot_wireframe`, not `plot_surface`

Comment: I don't think so because a wireframe would have completely see through filling. I would like the filling to be white (ie a different color than background)

Comment: That's what matlab mesh does though, it's not filled with white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
My guess is that you don't know the keyword argument `shade=...`, that by default is `True` but it seems that you prefer no shading.

Here it is the (very simple) code that produces the graph above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = y = np.linspace(0, 10, 51)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(y/7*x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2,
                       figsize=(10, 5),
                       layout='tight',
                       subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"))
ax[0].plot_surface(x, y, z, color='#F4FBFFFF', ec='black', lw=0.2, shade=True) # default
ax[1].plot_surface(x, y, z, color='#F4FBFFFF', ec='black', lw=0.2, shade=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To emulate the matlab plot, it was very important for me to properly set the cstride and rstride to be the same as matlab. In this case, to match the plot, I set cstride = 3 and rstride to 30.